# Is it semantically incorrect to use PUT for a "mark as favorite" operation?

Tags: rest, http, api-design

In my application I have 2 types: `user` and `file`. A `file` can be "marked as favorite" by a `user` to allow for easy access. I currently use the `PUT` method when "favoriting" a `file` like this:

```
PUT /user/fileList/
Body: { fileId: 'xxxx' }
```

The server will then add the given `fileId` to the user's record (authorization is handled seperately).

Is this use of `PUT` semantically incorrect or otherwise bad practice? Is there a better way to implement this pattern? It feels like an sub-optimal solution (at least semantically) to me.

Comment: Why do you need such a feature? If the client is interested in a resource it may safe its URI (bookmark) somewhere. The server shouldn't try to to maintain client state. Further, in its current form you would replace all "files" with a simple JSON document containing a `fieldId` item with value `xxxx`. The samantics of `PUT` are: Replace the current representation of the URI with the one provided in the payload. A server has a couple of options actually but it would take to much space to explain it here, but you can [read it up yourself](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.4)

Comment: @RomanVottner As for your first question: the `user`/`file` model is an analogy, the real use-case is a bit more complicated than that. It's not meant to be accessed directly, you need the client application for it to be of use, hence a bookmark doesn't make sense. Perhaps it's better to word the operation as 'save in account' rather than 'favoriting' (which is what it's called for the end-user).

As for the semantics: that seems very logical, would using `POST` make more sense here? I edited my question to clarify that we're dealing with a file*list* here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Github does this in their API for starring repositories for example.

https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/starring/#star-a-repository

The relevant difference between PUT and POST here is that clients should use PUT when they know the URL where a resource should be, e.g. `/user/starred/:owner/:repo`, and clients should use POST when they do not or should not know where the resource should be created, e.g. `POST /users` which should return a link to `/users/138`

To quote from RFC 2616, which defines HTTP 1.1:

> The PUT method requests that the enclosed entity be stored under the supplied Request-URI... If the Request-URI does not point to an existing resource, and that URI is
>   capable of being defined as a new resource by the requesting user agent, the origin server can create the resource
>   with that URI.
>
> The POST method is used to request that the origin server accept the entity enclosed in the request as a new
>   subordinate of the resource identified by the Request-URI in the Request-Line.

So in your specific case, I would put `fileId` somewhere in the URL (e.g. `/user/fileList/:fileId` rather than in the body, since the client knows where the resource should go.

Comment: Please, for the sake of whatever you wish for, but bury RFC 2616 now and forever and use [RFC 7231](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231) (or one of its sibling RFC's (7230-7235, maybe even 7236-2738) instead)

Comment: Although the Github API has a slightly different endpoint structure than me, this did provide me with the information I needed.
Just to be sure, if I understand your answer correctly the way I currently handle this operation would be incorrect, since I'm using `PUT` without a specific URI. So if I were to put the `fileId` in the URI or use the `POST` method, it would be semantically correct?

Comment: Yes that's right. You should put `fileId` in the URI. I would not use `POST` here, since you know what the URL should be.

Comment: Perhaps you could add that information to your answer, since it's the actual solution for my problem